# How do I call `with` directly on an object thats been fetched through a route with the same results as if it were fetched through `where`?

Tags: laravel

How do I call `with` directly on an object thats been automagically fetched through a route with the same results as if it were fetched through `where`?

**Let me explain through code!**

My route (same in both):

`Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostsController@show');`

**Alternative 1:**

My Controller:

```
public function show(Post $post){
    $postWithComments = Post::where('id', $post->id)->with('comments')->first();
}
```

Output: The comments of the intended post.

**Alternative 2:**

My Controller:

```
public function show(Post $post){
    $postWithComments = $post->with('comments')->first();
}
```

Output: The comments from the first of ALL posts.

Desired output: Same as alternative one.

---

**How can I modify the query in alternative 2 to output the same as alternative 1?**
I am thinking that it is unnecessary to make first the `where`-request as I already have the object loaded. So I am thinking that I would want to do this to reduce DB calls. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: as far i know, you shouldn't use `with` where you want to get data attached to one model instance. do it through relations

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

- Query related data with [lazy loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties):

  ```
  $post->comments; // this did the trick - comments for post will queried here
  return $post;  // here posts already has comments collection
  ```
- Setup [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) and use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

  At your `Post` model add `resolveRouteBinding` method:

  ```
  class Post extends Model 
  {
      public function resolveRouteBinding($id)
      {
          return $this->where('id', $id)->with(['comments'])->first();
      }
  }
  ```

  Then your controller will recieve Post instance with already loaded comments